# How do I refresh div contents on button click

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a script inside a div which I want to refresh when someone clicks a button with a unique ID.

I have some data which will be displayed inside the div - which I need to refresh without refreshing the whole page.

I've found a solution which changes a border colour but I can't quite simplify it to what I need. Here's what I have so far

```js
var storeColor = 'red';

$('#container').on('click', 'button', function() {
  var $p = $('#content p');
  var tmp = $p.css('border-color');
  $p.css('border-color', storeColor);
  storeColor = tmp;
});
```

```html
</div>
  <button type="button">Refresh DIV</button>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  
  Contents of div
    
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a few problems with your code... The button is outside of the container and thats the reason the click listener doesn't work. Inside the click function you try to access a paragraph `p` inside some element with the id `content` which doesn't exist in your code

```js
var storeColor = 'red';

$('#btnRefresh').on('click', function() {
  var $p = $('#container');
  $p.css('background-color', 'red');
  $p.html('hello world');
});
```

```html
  <button type="button" id="btnRefresh">Refresh DIV</button>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  
  Contents of div
    
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try changing the entire inner content of the div dynamically using document.querySelector('.div').innerHTML = `html string`

The above will not refresh the page if used upon a button click. You may want to use the preventDefault in the button's event listener too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).